# Wordpress xmlrpc request structure

Tags: wordpress, request, structure, xml-rpc, filemaker

I want to send an HTTP POST from FileMaker Pro to xmlrpc.php inside the WordPress directory that I host on my server.

I understand I can do this through cURL or class-IXR.php or class-wp-xmlrpc-server.php or some PHP or other intermediary software, but I do not want to use those (I want to compose the request myself). I see a lot of examples for using these functions. All of these functions compose something - a string of characters - that is ultimately sent to xmlrpc.php. I want to know how to write that request manually so I can direct FileMaker to write it.

Is this possible? Can I use a text editor to write a Wordpress xmlrpc request? If so, how do I do it? What is its format, requirements, etc.? I have not seen any discussion about the content or format of that request. I have examined the source for the classes mentioned above. Is my only option to reverse engineering them, or, has this been done already?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand "write a request manually"... A text editor and no programming language? How's that possible? Filemaker must have a communication protocol...

Comment: I mean not sending parameters to cURL or to the functions in a new class instance of class-IXR or class-wp-xmlrpc-server. I know these functions will properly format the request but I want to write it myself without having to use these functions. As I asked "Can I use a text editor to write a Wordpress xmlrpc request?" Once it is composed, FileMaker can post this request URL to the Wordpress xmlrpc via its "Insert from URL" script step. I just need to know how the request is structured so I can write it.